# Asking Questions When You've Found the Answer

Tags: discussion, site-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow: Should I answer my own question, or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not)

I recently ran into a problem that was particularly annoying and I was able to find the answer by a funky non-linear approach.  Hence, I'm thinking it might be good to document the post.  I seem to recall Joel a/o Jeff mentioning in a podcast that they want the trinity sites to be a repository of all answers.  In that line of reasoning I should post it, but I'm wondering if there is a way to post a question with answer so that people don't waste time testing and debugging only to find the solution that's already known.  Theoretically there could be other valid solutions, so maybe it makes sense to post it like a normal question, but I know I'd be cheesed to find out that I was re-inventing the wheel.  (Yeah, I know the question is subjective, but I'm hoping to find a consensus anyway)

Comment: duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23712/consistently-answering-your-own-questions & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/answering-your-own-question-immediately-closed

Comment: in general it is probably OK. And if you're thoughtful enough to ask here first, the odds of that go up exponentially :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is OK to answer your own questions. Here is a reference from the [stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).